# Cannot edit /System/Library/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf file on Mac OS (read-only)

Tags: macos, security, ssl, https

I'm trying to generate a CSR For a multi-domain EV. According to the instructions here...

https://easyengine.io/wordpress-nginx/tutorials/ssl/multidomain-ssl-subject-alternative-names/

...I need to edit the openssl.cnf file to allow me to configure 3 domains for my multi-domain EV. However, I can't seem to edit the cnf file. I've tried sudo and other methods but I can't save the changes to the file. Am I approaching this all wrong? Vim says I can't save changes to a "read-only" file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The instructions you are reading are incorrect. You don't need to edit that file.

Make a copy of OpenSSL configuration somewhere else, like your home directory, and use that configuration file instead of the default by passing the `-config` option to `openssl`.